# CSS animate two elements to overlay in middle

Tags: html, css

What is the simplest CSS for animating two elements to overlay each other when their parent is hovered on?

Here are two attempts I have done, each with separate issues.

1. https://codepen.io/ndullea/pen/RwNaXdJ

In this one they will both move, but it is not smooth because they have different parents and the elements are also misaligned because of that.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="bar"/>
</div>
<div class="container_two">
   <div class="bar_two"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.bar {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #29cf7c;
  width: 10px;
}

.bar_two {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #eb4034;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container:hover > .bar {
  transform: translateX(100px);
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.container:not(:hover) > .bar {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.container:hover > .bar_two {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.container:not(:hover) > .bar_two {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
```

2. https://codepen.io/ndullea/pen/wvBWwML

This one is smooth, but they both animate they same way (instead of going towards each other), I think because of the margin property.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bar"/>
    <div class="bar_two"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.bar {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #29cf7c;
  width: 10px;
}

.bar_two {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #eb4034;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container:hover > .bar {
  transform: translateX(100px);
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.container:not(:hover) > .bar {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.container:hover > .bar_two {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.container:not(:hover) > .bar_two {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
```

Comment: *animating two elements to overlay each other when their parent is hovered on*  What you mean overlay each other ? And do the elements have the same parent or each have it's own ?

Comment: By overlay, I mean one will be on top of the other. In regards to having the same parents or different, whatever is the simplest CSS to achieve a smooth animation (I am just trying to understand how to get both to move smoothly and end up in the same spot in the middle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your second fiddle with some improvements: https://jsfiddle.net/v1m0rsfj/11/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="bar"></div>
 <div class="bar_two"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 border: 2px solid #000;
}

.bar,
.bar_two {
 position: absolute;

 height: 100px;
 background-color: #29cf7c;
 width: 10px;
}

.bar {
}

.bar_two {
 left: 200px;

 background-color: #eb4034;
 z-index: 1;
}

.container:hover > .bar {
 transform: translateX(100px);
 transition: all .5s linear;
}

.container:not(:hover) > .bar {
 transform: translate(0px, 0px);
 transition: all .5s linear;
}

.container:hover > .bar_two {
 transform: translateX(-100px);
 transition: all .5s linear;
}

.container:not(:hover) > .bar_two {
 transform: translate(0px, 0px);
 transition: all .5s linear;
}
```

I found the biggest issue to be how you were closing your `div` tags `<div />` isn't the right way to close a `div` tag please use `<div></div>`

Also I found `margin-left` to be mis-positioning your element hence the changes to your css